# Changing part of the name of many files to unique names, using a spreadsheet of names

Tags: bash, files, filenames, rename

I need some help. I want to rename very many files with unique filenames using bash. I want to keep part of the original filename.

For example:

| current file name | new file name |
| --- | --- |
| F1.R23.fastq.gz | 10_1.F1.R23.fastq.gz |
| F2.R7.fastq.gz | empty_3_1.F2.R7.fastq.gz |
| F32.R3.fastq.gz | 63_3.F32.R3.fastq.gz |
| F5.R7.fastq.gz | Blank_3.F5.R7.fastq.gz |
| F2.R2.fastq.gz | N5_1.F2.R2.fastq.gz |

What I have, is a file containing a column with the original names, and a column containing what I want to add to the names. Like so:

| file | sample |
| --- | --- |
| F1.R23.fastq.gz | 10_1 |
| F2.R7.fastq.gz | empty_3_1 |
| F32.R3.fastq.gz | 63_3 |
| F5.R7.fastq.gz | Blank_3 |
| F2.R2.fastq.gz | N5_1 |

I would really appreciate if anybody has a way of doing this. I have potentially thousands of files to rename, some with complicated names and in a random order, and so it’s not really feasible to do this by hand.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a csv file called `files-to-rename.csv`, or convert the spreadsheet you have to CSV format. The contents of the file should be like this:

```
F1.R23.fastq.gz,10_1
F2.R7.fastq.gz,empty_3_1
F32.R3.fastq.gz,63_3
F5.R7.fastq.gz,Blank_3
F2.R2.fastq.gz,N5_1
```

Then run this command, making sure you are in the same directory as the files:

```bsh
while IFS=$',\r' read -r source dest ; do
  mv -v "$source" "${dest}.${source}"
done < files-to-rename.csv
```

The above will not work if the csv file has DOS line endings. You can use the `dos2unix files-to-rename.csv` command to make sure the file is in UNIX line endings.

---

Otherwise, use this safer snippet below:

```bsh
while read line; do
  source=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f1)
  dest=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2)

  mv -v "$source" "${dest}.${source}"
done < files-to-rename.csv
```

Comment: I'd adapt the `mv` command to attempt the rename only if the source existed and the destination did not - `[ -f "$source" ] && [ ! -f "$dest.$source" ] && mv "$source" "$dest.$source"`. The first time through I'd also suggest amending `mv` to `echo mv` so the OP can see what's going on without actually changing any of the file names

Comment: Consider using `while IFS=$',\r' read -r source dest junk`. Not only is it cleaner to split directly at a comma, but it will also handle an unexpected trailing CR (allowing for the possibility that the CSV was converted from the spreadsheet on a Windows system)

Comment: @roaima Thanks. Updated the answer. However, your solution will end up having weird chars in the renamed file if the csv file has DOS line endings.

Comment: @GMaster, in Bash that seems to work for a single trailing CR, but not for two. It doesn't work in zsh though. `IFS=$',\r' read -r a b x` and ignoring `x` seems like it might work better. Or maybe it's better to just pipe the input through `tr -d '\r'`.